# How to add these more than one apply_filters(content, value) without linebreak?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

```
<div class="oneColumnHeader">
    <h1>
        <strong><?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $header1) ?></strong>
        <?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $text1) ?>
    </h1>
</div>
```

I thought display:inline; in h1 would have done the trick, but it did not.
Any answers to how this works, so they dont come out with linebreaks?

My SCSS right now:

```
.oneColumnHeader {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    h1 {
        font-weight: 500;
    }
    strong {
        color: $orange-color;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

Did not have to do anything with the SCSS-file, could just simply:

```
<strong><?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $header1."&nbsp;</strong>".$text1) ?>
```